# decltype(auto) in C++11 - deducing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, auto, decltype

auto deduction of return types is possible in C++14 but I am trying to write something similar in C++11 i.e.

If I were to write in C++14, it would be

```
struct MyTypeA{
    std::vector<int> _d;
};

struct MyTypeB{
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
    MyTypeA _data;
};

decltype(auto) MakeObject(const MyTypeA& obj) {
    return std::make_tuple(obj._vec);
}

decltype(auto) MakeObject(const MyTypeB& obj) {
    return std::make_tuple(obj._id, obj._name, std::make_tuple(MakeObject(obj._data)));
}
```

The above is C++14 and I can rewrite `MakeObject` something similar in C++11 as below,

```
auto MakeObject (const MyTypeA& obj) -> decltype( std::make_tuple(obj._d)){
    return std::make_tuple(obj._d);
};

auto MakeObject (const MyTypeB& obj) -> decltype( std::make_tuple(obj._id, obj._name, std::make_tuple(MakeObject(obj._data)))){
    return std::make_tuple(obj._id, obj._name, std::make_tuple(MakeObject(obj._data)));
};
```

And as you can see I have a bunch of overloaded non-member functions. Though this works, it seems very verbose and redundant code. Is there a better way to do this in C++11?

Comment: You mention lambdas, but I can't see a single lambda in your question. Did you mean "trailing return types" instead?

Comment: I don't quite get what you say about lambdas. The code you posted does not make use of any lambda function. If lambdas (not having a named function) is sufficient for you, you can easily use them, since they already have automatic return type deduction if there is only a single return statement in c++11.

Comment: Sorry guys. My bad, I pasted non-lambda code and forgot to change the text. Am not using lambda

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this in C++11?

While return type of a regular function cannot be deduced prior to C++14, the return type of lambda can. And a non-capturing lambda behaves much like a function. So, in C++11 you could do

```
auto MakeObject = [](const MyTypeA& obj) {
     return std::make_tuple(obj._vec);
}
```

However, this doesn't allow for overloading, which you use. If you need overloading, then the trailing decltype may be a better choice.

Comment: exactly, I can't overload the lambdas. Not sure if there's a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
#define RETURNS(...) decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

Then you get

```
auto MakeObject(const MyTypeA& obj)
->RETURNS(std::make_tuple(obj._vec))
```

This may or may not be considered better.  But it does remove the DRY violation.